# Porque o JobScheduler está executando sem o celular está carregando?

Tags: android

Fiz uma aplicação utilizando a classe [JobScheduler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) que veio agora na api do lolipop.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre a estrutura da aplicação porque ela está rodando e funcionando corretamente.

Meu ponto é sobre uma opção que existe na construção de um JobScheduler:

Para se criar um Job você deve saber que se utiliza o [JobInfo.Builder](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html) onde existe a opção [setRequiresCharging(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiresCharging(boolean))...

Enfim, minha aplicação cria esses jobs, na verdade a aplicação nada mais é que uma tela de cadastro de jobs... Eu criei dois Jobs um só para rodar com ele carregando e outro sem ele carregando. Ele roda a cada 2 minutos esse Job que ele precisa estar carregando.

O problema é que ele roda as duas tasks com o celular fora do carregador. Estou rodando isso em um Nexus 5 com android 6 já.

Alguém sabe o motivo dele rodar um Job que foi criado com o `setRequiresCharging` como `true` mesmo com o celular não carregando?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

A maneira que eu tenho de verificar se o Job está rodando é criando um notificação com a hora precisa que ele executou, cada job tem sua notificação e administra ela, esquema padrão de se ela não existe ele cria e exibe, se ela já está sendo exibida ele atualiza a hora da execução, isso está funcionando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Achei o problema com essa classe.

Esse [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81265) está aberto a um ano e parece que ainda não foi resolvido.

Assim que eu tiver uma atualização sobre a data de uma possível atualização vou editar essa pergunta com a solução.